# Is it possible to run a function after the app is killed?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, background-process

#### Hi there!

I have read a lot of forums etc. about this topic and I have gained some knowlegde, but I still don't know weather it is at all possible.

##### Info

I'm using the Ionic Framework

##### Problem

I have an app which controls a IOT device using a network request (http/https).
Since the IOT device does not have functionality to automatically turn off after a specific time setting, I want the app to send this command after approx. 120 min. (2 hours).

So the user, when the app is opened, press a button to power down the device after 120 min. and then closes the app (kills completely, not in background).
Now I want the app to automatically send this power down command to the IOT device after 120 min.

I'm using Ionic Framework but can implement Native functionality and modules if it is possible this way.

##### What I think I know:

This should be possible on Android implementing a 'service' natively which I understand is a sort of deamon thread or resembles a Windows service. (exactly what I need).

iOS seems to be the problem, with a lot of restrictions on code execution after the app has been closed, or even stopped by the operating system. I've read on this thread (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685525) that some cases are possible (music playing in background, fetching big files from the internet, etc.).
They also provide something they call PushKit https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit. But that seems to only be able to notify the user, and auto power down is not smart if I have to send a request to the user that the 120 min. are up, now you can turn of your device yourself xD

##### Question

So my question is, will this be possible at all on either operating system (Android, iOS) or will I have to implement a server that will send the request to the IOT device instead?

##### TLDR

Is it at all possible to send a HTTP request after 120 min. on iOS and Android after the user has manually closed the app (killed the app)?

I have looked through a lot of forums and has not found a definitive answer to this question.
I expect that it will not be possible on iOS but only on Android.

Many threads on this topic is approx. 8-12 years old, so maybe some new possibilities has come to light?

Comment: On iOS when the app is dead, it is dead. It cannot execute any more code